# NgRx @Effect vs createEffect

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, decorator, ngrx

What is the difference between `createEffect` vs `@Effect` annotation in ngrx?

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactsEffects {

constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private contactsService: ContactsService,
    private contactsSocket: ContactsSocketService
  ) {}


  destroy$ = createEffect( () => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(remove),
    pluck('id'),
    switchMap( id => this.contactsService.destroy(id).pipe(
      pluck('id'),
      map(id => removeSuccess({id}))
    ))
  ));

  @Effect()
  liveCreate$ = this.contactsSocket.liveCreated$.pipe(
    map(contact => createSuccess({contact}))
  );

}
```

Answer (score 15):

@ngrx/effects
createEffect for type safety
As alternative to the `@Effect()` decorator, NgRx 8 provides the `createEffect` function. The advantage of using `createEffect` is that it’s type-safe, if the effect does not return an `Observable<Action>` it will give compile errors. The option `{ dispatch: false }` still exists for effects that don’t dispatch new Actions, adding this option also removes the restriction that an effect needs to return an `Observable<Action>`.

Starting from NgRx 8 by default, automatically resubscribe to the effect when this happens. This adds a safety net for where the unhappy paths were missed.
It’s possible to turn this feature off by setting `resubscribeOnError` to false at the effect level.
example:

```
login$ = createEffect(() => .....), { resubscribeOnError: false });
```